# Why is this code resulting in bad access?

Tags: c++, audio, exc-bad-access, juce

```
WildcardFileFilter wavFiles = WildcardFileFilter("*.wav", "", "wavFiles");

fileChooser = new FileBrowserComponent(
                   FileBrowserComponent::FileChooserFlags::openMode
                   | FileBrowserComponent::FileChooserFlags::canSelectFiles
                   | FileBrowserComponent::FileChooserFlags::canSelectDirectories,
                   File("/Users/harrygardiner/Desktop"), &wavFiles, nullptr);
```

I'm trying to isolate .wav files in my audio application but it keeps telling me I have bad access problems, why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `wavFiles` lives on the Stack. `fileChooser` is probably outliving `wavFiles` and then tries to access it resulting in undefined behaviour.